# How contrastive loss work intuitively in siamese network

Tags: deep-learning, loss-function, siamese-network

I am having issue in getting clear concept of contrastive loss used in siamese network.

Here is pytorch formula

```
torch.mean((1-label) * torch.pow(euclidean_distance, 2) +
                                      (label) * torch.pow(torch.clamp(margin - euclidean_distance, min=0.0), 2))
```

where margin=2.

If we convert this to equation format, it can be written as

```
(1-Y)*D^2 + Y* max(m-d,0)^2
```

Y=0, if both images are from same class
Y=1, if both images are from different class

What i think, if images are from same class the distance between embedding should decrease.   and if images are from different class, the distance should increase.

I am unable to map this concept to contrastive loss.

Let say, if Y is 1 and distance value is larger, the first part become zero `(1-Y)`, and second also become zero, because it should choose whether `m-d` or 0 is bigger.
So the loss is zero which does not make sense.
Can you please help me to understand this

Answer (score 0):

If the distance of a negative sample is greater than the specified margin, it should be already separable from a positive sample. Therefore, there is no benefit in pushing it farther away.

For details please check this [blog post](https://medium.com/@maksym.bekuzarov/losses-explained-contrastive-loss-f8f57fe32246), where the concept of "Equilibrium" gets explained and why the Contrastive Loss makes reaching this point easier.